# Combine link_to and icon helpers in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, font-awesome, prawn, prawnto

I'm using the icon helper for the "font-awesome-sass" gem. I'm also using link_to to link to a PDF that is being generated using prawn and prawnto. How can I combine these two lines to I have a font-awesome link to my pdf?

```
<p><%= link_to "PDF", hotel_shell_path(@hotel_shell, :format => 'pdf') %></p>
```

and

```
<a><%= icon("file-pdf-o", "", class: "", href: '#') %></a>
```

Thanks in advance. If you need more details, let me know.

Comment: Can you please add, to your question, the resulting html which you want to generate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this, a `link_to` with `do` block :

```
<%= link_to  hotel_shell_path(@hotel_shell, :format => 'pdf')  do %>
  <%= icon("file-pdf-o", "", class: "", href: '#') %>
<% end %>
```